# How can I add a new method in the response object in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to add a custom wrapper for res.json where I'll do some preprocessing before sending the response.

The two things I tried are:

First, adding a wrapper method on the `express.response` object:

```
var express = require("express");
express.response.customJSON = function() {
  // my wrapper goes here
};
```

Second, adding a middleware where I write the wrapper:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  res.customJSON = function() {
    // my wrapper goes here
  }
  next();
}
```

The problem with the first approach is that I clutter my `app.js` file with a lot of code since I want to have multiple wrappers for different response types.

The problem with the second approach is that a new `customJSON` function is created for each response. I could use `util.inherit` and add to the response prototype but I am not sure how to do this in a safe way.

Do you have any suggestions? How can I do this?

Comment: Apart from editing the express source code, adding a wrapper like you did is really your only viable option...

Comment: Yes but which option is the best?

Comment: I would personally prefer the first one you did. If you're worried about cluttering app.js with multiple blocks of wrapper code, you can just move it over to a separate file, then require it in app.js and pass your instance of express as a parameter to the setup.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Is this considered good practice in Node?

Comment: You can create a new module containing all functions you want to add to res object. Then you can import the required functions and add them to res where required.

Comment: Either will work. I prefer the second one because it works within the existing middleware framework instead of modifying stuff globally. If you are concerned about the overhead of creating a function on every request, all you need to do is factor it into a standalone function; then `res.customJSON = customJsonStandaloneFunc;`. This can be done within a module to keep things self-contained.